# Wrong shape when converting RGB array into image by plt.imshow()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I was trying to make a filter in python to achieve oil painting effect. It seems that the filter works perfectly, but something went wrong when I was trying to convert RGB array into image.

code:

```
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from PIL import Image
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

plt.figure("hist",figsize=(8,8))

img_4_1=io.imread("img_2.jpg")
arr_4_1=img_4_1.flatten()
arr_4_1=arr_4_1.reshape(333,500,3)*255
arr_4_1.flags["WRITEABLE"]=False
arr_4_2=np.copy(arr_4_1)
arr_4_2.flags["WRITEABLE"]=True
intensity=10
radius=2
check_intensity=np.zeros((intensity+1)*4).reshape((intensity+1),4)

for x in range(2,arr_4_1.shape[0]-2):
    for y in range(2,arr_4_1.shape[1]-2):
        for i in range(-radius,radius+1):
            for j in range(-radius,radius+1):
                temp_r=int(arr_4_1[x+i][y+j][0])
                temp_g=int(arr_4_1[x+i][y+j][1])
                temp_b=int(arr_4_1[x+i][y+j][2])
                temp=(((temp_r+temp_g+temp_b)/3)*intensity)/255
                if temp>intensity:
                    temp=intensity
                check_intensity[int(temp)][0]+=1
                check_intensity[int(temp)][1]+=temp_r
                check_intensity[int(temp)][2]+=temp_g
                check_intensity[int(temp)][3]+=temp_b
        max_intensity=0
        for h in range(1,intensity):
            if check_intensity[h][0]-check_intensity[h-1][0]>0:
                max_intensity=h
        final_r=round(check_intensity[max_intensity][1]/check_intensity[max_intensity][0])
        final_g=round(check_intensity[max_intensity][2]/check_intensity[max_intensity][0])
        final_b=round(check_intensity[max_intensity][3]/check_intensity[max_intensity][0])
        if final_r>255:
            final_r=255
        if final_g>255:
            final_g=255
        if final_b>255:
            final_b=255
        for k in range(-radius,radius+1):
            for l in range(-radius,radius+1):
                arr_4_2[x+k][y+l][0]=final_r
                arr_4_2[x+k][y+l][1]=final_g
                arr_4_2[x+k][y+l][2]=final_b
        check_intensity=np.zeros((intensity+1)*4).reshape((intensity+1),4)
        
plt.figure("hist",figsize=(8,8))
plt.subplot(221)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(arr_4_1) # original picture
plt.subplot(222)
ar_4_1=arr_4_1[:,:,0].flatten()
plt.hist(ar_4_1, bins=256, density=True, facecolor='r',edgecolor='r')
ag_4_1=arr_4_1[:,:,1].flatten()
plt.hist(ag_4_1, bins=256, density=True, facecolor='g',edgecolor='g')
ab_4_1=arr_4_1[:,:,2].flatten()
plt.hist(ab_4_1, bins=256, density=True, facecolor='b',edgecolor='b')
plt.xlim(0,255)
plt.subplot(223)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(arr_4_2) # oil painting effects
plt.subplot(224)
ar_4_2=arr_4_2[:,:,0].flatten()
plt.hist(ar_4_2, bins=256, density=True, facecolor='r',edgecolor='r')
ag_4_2=arr_4_2[:,:,1].flatten()
plt.hist(ag_4_2, bins=256, density=True, facecolor='g',edgecolor='g')
ab_4_2=arr_4_2[:,:,2].flatten()
plt.hist(ab_4_2, bins=256, density=True, facecolor='b',edgecolor='b')
plt.xlim(0,255)
```

original picture(img_2.jpg): [img_2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nme7P.jpg)

output picture:[output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7jEQ.png)

I think the crucial parts are these:

1. converted the flattened array into a 3D array
2. used np.copy to create arr_4_2
3. changed the elements in arr_4_2, while arr_4_1 remained the same
4. tried to reform the array into image, but failed

The failed parts are:

1. the wrong shape, which should be (333,500)
2. the wrong colors, which shouldn't be that blue

I mainly want to fix the shape, and if anyone knows how to fix the colors that's so good.

I have tried Image.fromarray() in PIL, which also failed.

Comment: Not sure what the point of the initial flatten + reshape is, other than wasting CPU (and causing your problems). The output of the `io.read` is a numpy array of shape `(500, 333, 3)`. What do you hope to achieve by reshaping it to `(333,500,3)` ?

Comment: Maybe forgot that numpy arrays are by default indexed in row-major order?

Comment: I have found the resolution, thank you Dan. The core is that I do forget the arrays are indexed in row-major order, so when I reshape it, it was formed is a wrong way. BTW I did it before is because I referred to another code. Again, thank you so much.